# socket.io send data to client based on id passed by client

Tags: node.js, architecture, express, socket.io

Say I have a rest end point which when called starts a long running process server side e.g.

```
http://host/api/program/start
```

and I want to push any updates / output from that process from the server side to a client.

I'm thinking the rest call would return some sort of unique id which the client could then use when connecting to the websocket to only receive updates about that particular process.

I'd have to think about buffering the output / updates from the process to send to the client if they didn't connect before the first output from the process but irrespective of that, what would be the best way of achieving the socket data handling for this? Could I make use of the socket.io rooms / namespaces in some way?

Comment: Huh..What would I be using an IP address for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it this way, I would suggest generating the ID via the initial `start` call, then passing that to the long running process as an argument. Then that process publishes all messages to that ID (which appropriate clients are listening to as well).

However, I would discourage you from going from this approach. There are plenty of ways to go about handling a child process in Node, so you might want to look into these options a little more so you don't end up dealing with zombie processes all over the place.

The first that comes to mind is [ChildProcess](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Another option would be something like [WebWorker Threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads). Either of these would be right in the vein of what (I think) you're trying to do, but allow you to maintain much more control over the child processes.

Comment: Yea that isn't such a problem, I've already done all that using child process in node. I'm capturing the stdout and stderr or the process but want to push this (live via websockets) to a connected client / clients who have provided the id to listen to this process. It's the bit about how to target the specific socket, rather than sending to all sockets / broadcasting the output..

Comment: Then I don't think I'm sure what the original issue is. I would do exactly as you stated and generate a unique string to use as the WebSocket namespace when you spawn the child process.

Comment: Cheers, I'll check out WS namespaces then - it was this I was part I was wondering about. Whether rooms/namespaces would be appropriate or whether I would need to work something else out backend-wise.

Comment: Cool! That's the way I've always done it in the past, but maybe someone else will comment with a better solution. Best of luck :)

Comment: Realised I hadn't accepted an answer for this, it was quite a long time ago now but I remember using namespaces in the end so accepting this answer and the conversation that followed as the answer. Cheers